# shell commandline input linechange comma to space

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I have simple script that takes 4 variables from interactive keyboard 'read' however my command has a comma in it. I read on IFS separator value, yet examples only show it reading from files not keyboard input. Is there a trick do changing the input, or do I need to pipe the command through SED/AWK to be the correct format for the script to read?

Script is nothing fancy, just input text, and it adds the input value and echos back command strings that can be run with the entered text.

[network] [card],[port] [hostname]
0123 0123,A1 ABCDEFG

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter network info:"
read VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4
#I have no clue what Im doing

echo -e "${green}ping test and ssh into $VAR4${NC}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To treat a comma as a word separator, try:

```
IFS="$IFS," read a b c d
```

This temporarily adds a comma to `IFS`, which is the list of characters that the shell uses for field separators.

As an example, let's gather some input:

```
$ IFS="$IFS," read a b c d
1, 2,3 , 4
```

Let's see how bash interpreted that input:

```
$ echo "a=$a b=$b c=$c d=$d"
a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4
```

#### Improvement

We can combine the prompt and the read command:

```
IFS="$IFS," read -p "Enter network info: " a b c d
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> **IFS**
>   The  Internal  Field  Separator  that  is  used  for  word 
>   splitting  after  expansion  and to split lines into words with the
>   read builtin command.  The default value is
>       `<space><tab><newline>`

#### Alternative

If, for some unspecified reason, one really wanted to use `sed` to this task:

```
read -p "Enter network info: " a b c d < <(sed 's/,/ /g; q')
```

The command `s/,/ /g` tells sed to replace every comma with a space.  `q` tells it to quit after the first line.

The lone `<` indicates *redirection*: it tells the shell to get its input for the `read` command from the file-like object that follows on the command line.

The construct `<(...)` is called *process substitution* and creates a file-like object from the command contained in the parens.  That command is the `sed` command which replaces commas with spaces.

For the same approach but using with awk:

```
read -p "Enter network info: " a b c d < <(awk '{gsub(/,/, " "); print; exit}')
```